# command design pattern usage

Tags: design-patterns, uml, command

I've read 3 descriptions of the command design pattern:
[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), [dofactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternCommand.aspx) and [source making](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command/c%2523).

In all of them, the UML shows a relation between the client to the receiver & the concrete command, but no relation to the invoker.
But in all 3 examples the client is the one that initiates the invoker and call its Execute method.

I think that should be a relation to the invoker as well. Am I missing somthing in here? Maybe even a basic UML knowladge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably a limitation of the simple examples.  There is no need to have a relationship between the client and the invoker in practice.

The client could serialise the command object and send it to a remote service for execution for example, or the client may add the command to a queue for another thread to de-queue and execute later on.

Comment: Hi there. Could you elaborate a little bit more on how the client could serialize a command object and send it to a remote service? If we imagine that there is a command object entitled "CreateGameCommand" that is a concrete "Command" class. Is this the object we would send over a TCP/IP socket to a remove service? Would the server then call the 'execute()' method on this object? Or would the client call the 'execute()' method first? Many thanks

Comment: @Joeblackdev - Yes, you would serialise the CreateGameCommand using whatever on-the-wire format you like (binary, XML, whatever) and send it to the server and the server would deserialise and call the execute() method on that object.